# jQuery selection by finding className

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create something whereby when the user clicks on the month in the `li`, jquery will find the `className` and look for the same `classNme` in the rest of the document, and as a result only display this `className` from the `<p>`.

e.g clicking on

```
<li class="jan15">JAN</li>
```

will only display

```
<div class="jan15"><p>January 2015</p></div>
```

I'm having problems putting a jquery together. I can manage to find the class name, but once it's found, I can't work out how to search the whole document for this class.

```
<div>
<ol>
    <li class="years">2015
        <ol>
            <li class="jan15"><a href="#">JAN</a></li>
            <li class="feb15"><a href="#">FEB</a></li>
            <li class="mar15"><a href="#">MAR</a></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="years">2014
        <ol>
          <li class="jan14"><a href="#">JAN</a></li>
            <li class="feb14"><a href="#">FEB</a></li>
            <li class="mar14"><a href="#">MAR</a></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
</div>


<div class="jan15">
 <p>january 2015</p>
</div>
<div class="feb15">
 <p>february 2015</p>
</div>
<div class="mar15">
 <p>march 2015</p>
</div>
<div class="jan14">
 <p>january 2014</p>
</div>
<div class="feb14">
 <p>february 2014</p>
</div>
<div class="mar14">
 <p>march 2014</p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.years li').click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass(this.className)){
        $('.months' + this.className).show();
} else {
$('.months').hide();
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/30aqp3mj/2/

edited with jQuery and new jsfiddle link

Comment: This will get downvoted a lot if you don't show your effort. That fiddle has no JS, so it's basically "someone do my code".

Comment: using just a simple `$('.CLASSNAME')` will select every element in the page that has that classname.

Comment: probably need a `.not(this)` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do more along these lines:

```
$('.' + this.className.match(/\w{3}\d{2}/)).not(this).show().siblings().hide()
```

Snippet below is commented more thoroughly.  Also, note that for this to work, the elements to be shown or hidden need to be siblings.  To do that, just wrap them in a `<div>` or whatever.

```js
$('.years li').on('click', function(){
  $('.' + this.className.match(/\w{3}\d{2}/)) // Get the date-like class and use it
                                              // in a jQuery selector.
  
  .not(this)                                  // Specify to not include the link you
                                              // clicked.
  
  .show()                                     // Run the current slection of elements
                                              // against the `show` method
  
  .siblings()                                 // Fetch the other hideable elements
  
  
  .hide()                                     // Hide them.
});
```

```css
li {list-style-type: none; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <ol>
    <li class="years">2015
     <ol>
      <li class="jan15">JAN</li>
      <li class="feb15">FEB</li>
      <li class="mar15">MAR</li>
     </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="years">2014
     <ol>
        <li class="jan14">JAN</li>
      <li class="feb14">FEB</li>
      <li class="mar14">MAR</li>
     </ol>
    </li>
   </ol>
  </div>

<div>
  <div class="jan15">
    <p>january 2015</p>
  </div>
  <div class="feb15">
    <p>february 2015</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mar15">
    <p>march 2015</p>
  </div>
  <div class="jan14">
    <p>january 2014</p>
  </div>
  <div class="feb14">
    <p>february 2014</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mar14">
    <p>march 2014</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was after

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the logic a little bit in your jquery but it seems to work

Hope it helps

```
$('.years li a').click(function() {
  className = $(this).parent().attr('class');

  // Only clicked will be visible
  $('.months > div').hide();

  if ($('div.'+className).length > 0){
    $('div.'+className).show();
  }
});
```

and css

```
.months > div{
  display:none;
}
```